# Ajax doesn't trigger success - ASP

Tags: asp.net, ajax

First of all I looked trough a lot of same questions on stack. My problem is as follows:

I'm working on a *school* project to make a card game (ginrummy)
In this web application (mvc 4) I want to move cards to sets (right side) and I want to do this with ajax.

added a picture to clearify.

[image]

The ajax perfectly triggers the controller and perfectly bring over the data I put through. 
In firebug I checked the response and it even added a card to the right correct set

**The problem is when the ajax is done, it doesn't trigger the succes function neither it updates the page.**

Note: This is my first time I work with ajax.
The complete function returns OK status.

Now the code:

View:

```
      var GameId = @Model.Id
        $(function () {
            $(".droppable").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var id = ui.draggable.find("a").attr("data-CardId");
                    var location = droppableId = $(this).attr("id");

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("ChangeCardLocation")',
                        data: { 'id': GameId, 'cardId': id, 'location': location },
                        succes: function () {
                            alert('wow');
                        },
                        complete:function (){

                        }
                    });


                }
            });
        });
```

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult ChangeCardLocation(int id, int cardId, Location location)
        {
            var game = db.Games.Find(id);
            var card = db.Cards.Find(cardId);

            game.ChangeCardLocationTo(card, location);

            db.SaveChanges();

            game.Info = game.GetInfo(id);


            if (game.GameState == GameState.playerOneLayOn || game.GameState == GameState.playerTwoLayOn)
            {
                return View("LastTurn", game);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Details", game);
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions on what is going wrong?
I'm a student and it is for a school project!

@comment:

When I did this:

```
  error: function(xhr, error){
                            console.log(error);
                            console.log(xhr);
                        },
```

I noticed it didn't get triggerd.
After that I tried the same in complete:

```
complete:function (xhr, error){
                            console.log(error);
                            console.log(xhr);
                        }
```

The result was

- succes
- object that returned readystate 4

**I misspelled success thats in the first part it wasn't working. But my next question is how do make it updating the contents of the page that the ajax call is getting back.**

I am trying myself offcourse now. In the data succes is getting is my whole page delivered as I want to have it.

Comment: Check the error callback function of the ajax call, it will give more in terms of what went wrong.

Comment: Updated my question with a resposne @iaimtomisbehave

Comment: to go further @alxandr comment below. I hope there is a other way than windows.location.reload() because it would look much nicer and it causes a problem with a other function in my code

Comment: I've learned alot. Thanks for all responds. Question closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it because you have misspelt "success"?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("ChangeCardLocation")',
    data: { 'id': GameId, 'cardId': id, 'location': location },
    success: function () {
        alert('wow');
    },
    complete:function (){
    }
});
```

Comment: Ouch, this hurts. But thanks for giving me the good answer!
Also do you have any idea how I make the page refresh after this with ajax?

Comment: @JochemTheSchoolKid: Depends on your definition of "refresh with ajax". Refreshing a page is as simple as window.location.reload(). However, refreshing only the content can't be done in a standard way, it depends on your sever/page.

Comment: why can't it be done in the standard way? can you explain more about this how it depends on my server/page?

Comment: @JochemTheSchoolKid The point of using Ajax call is to partially update your page without reloading your entire page. When the ajax call returns in your case it would return a partial page or data for that part of the page. You want add/remove/update just the data that is returned.

Comment: How can I arrange in asp.net mvc 4 that it would only return e.g. "second set" (it is a div and it is also a location. Location is a enum)?

Comment: Look into Partial Views that will help get subset of the page back.

Comment: or should I reload the div where it is placed in with this the data out the ajax call?. Lets look into that